# How to do a dump of database for only one day in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has data starting from 2015 up to 2019 and I would like to do a dump of only one day like 21-12-2019 . The problem am faced with not all tables has timestamp/datetime datatype.

e.g table1 has date field, table has no date field.

I have a script of how to do a dump using where condition;
mysqldump database table_bname --where=“date_column BETWEEN ‘2012-07-01 00:00:00’ and ‘2012-12-01 00:00:00’” but when I use this one I get an error of table missing date column.

Can anyone help on how to solve this??

Comment: If there is no date in a table, how would anyone solve your problem of only exporting data from one date ?

Comment: I think you mean `date_column BETWEEN ‘2012-07-01 00:00:00’ and ‘2012-11-30 23:59:59’`, otherwise you'll get boundary rows twice. You might be able to figure out which rows of a date-less table were created on a day if they are child rows of a table with a date, but detecting updates would be hard/impossible. It sounds like you're going to have write some SQL...